# jQuery $.data(): Possible misuse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perhaps I'm using $.data incorrectly.

Assigning the data:

```
var course_li = sprintf('<li class="draggable course">%s</li>', course["fields"]["name"]);

$(course_li).data('pk', course['pk']);
alert(course['pk']); // shows a correct value

alert($(course_li).data('pk')); // shows null. curious...
```

`course_li` is later appended to the DOM.

Moving the `li` to a different `ul`:

```
function moveToTerm(item, term) {
    item.fadeOut(function() {
        item.appendTo(term).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Trying to access the data later:

```
$.each($(term).children(".course"), function(index, course) {
      var pk = $(course).data('pk');
      // pk is undefined
      courses.push(pk);
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I have confirmed that the course `li` on which I am setting the data is the same as the one on which I am looking for it. (Unless I'm messing that up by calling `appendTo()` on it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store the data:

```
$(course_li).data('pk', course['pk']);
```

you're creating an element but not saving it, so it's lost. Your alert test test the wrong value; it should be:

```
$(course_li).data('pk', course['pk']);
alert($(course_li).data('pk'));
```

which is `null`. Consider:

```
$(course_li);
$(course_li);
```

This creates two different elements with source equal to `course_li`, which are then promptly lost. What you need to do is create the element first, then work with that single element (i.e. don't call `$(course_li)` more than once). For example,

```
var course_li = $(sprintf('<li class="draggable course">%s</li>', 
                          course["fields"]["name"]));
course_li.data('pk', course['pk']);
parent.append(course_li);
```

Note that `course_li` now holds an element, rather than a string.

Comment: `course_li` is saved back to the DOM, if that's what you meant. (updated the OP to show that.)

Comment: But you are correct that that `alert()` shows `null`. Why is that? How do I save the data?

Answer (score 1):

try checking to see if the element being created by this call:

```
$(course_li)
```

is a single 'li' element, or a div. From the doco:

> When the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example... snip ...Specifically, jQuery creates a new <div> element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in

So it's probably creating a div that you are assigning the data to, so when you select the 'li' itself, you are getting a child of the actual element that you set the data on.

Comment: Note that the <div> jQuery creates isn't included in the result, only its children are.